# Matplotlib changes channels of image when saving

Tags: image, matplotlib, image-processing

I am using matplotlib to read an image, but the number of channels changes after I save the original image with `imsave`. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('sample.tiff')

print(img.shape)

mpimg.imsave('sample2.tiff', img)


img2 = mpimg.imread('sample2.tiff')

print(img2.shape)
```

And here is the output:

```
(2160, 2160)
(2160, 2160, 4)
```

The image becomes a 4-channel image while it was 1-channel originally. And it seems that the final channel is always 255.
What is happening here? And the original image looks meaning less as it is all black. But when I read & save it with `imread` and `imsave`, I can finally see some meaningful figures.

Comment: Create some reproducible example incl. the image and also add what version of matplotlib you are using. After that, one could reason about mpl's backend-reader, which probably is pillow, despite the change to imageio in scipy and skimage. One could also try their readers/writers of course. tiff is one of those very complex formats (even if this example looks simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not the first person to have this problem - [see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3657).

My suggestion would be to use `imageio` (or PIL) to save the image (in fact, to read it too) and it works fine:

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('a.tif')

imageio.imwrite('result.tif',img)
```

Answer (score 2):

The input image `sample.tiff` is a one channel gray scale image. One cannot know why that is the case, it simply depends on where you got that image from.

`imread` converts this image to a 2D numpy array.

When given a 2D numpy array as input `imsave` will apply a colormap to the array, and, without further arguments given, apply a normalization between the minimum and maximum data value. The resulting image is hence a color image with 4 channels.

`imread` then converts this image to a 3D numpy array.